# join data.frames according to rule in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

I have the following data.frame (data.frame_1) which goes from 2019-10-01 to 2020-10-01 for each `clinic_code` and is the main data.frame with many variables (only a few shown below):

```
date            clinic_code    partner_code     
2019-10-01      A05            NA
2019-11-01      A05            NA
               .....
2020-10-01      A05            NA
2019-10-01      A12            NA
2019-11-01      A12            NA
2019-12-01      A12            NA
2020-01-01      A12            00044
2019-10-01      B17            NA
2019-11-01      B17            NA
               .....
2020-03-01      B17            00045
2020-04-01      B17            00045
2020-05-01      B17            00049
               .....
2020-10-01      B17            00049
```

and then an older one (data.frame_2) which goes from 2019-10-01 to 2020-02-31:

```
clinic_code    partner_code    partnership_start_date    partnership_end_date
A05            00033           2019-10-01                NA
A12            00001           2019-10-01                NA
A12            00001           2019-10-01                2019-12-31 
A12            00044           2020-01-01                NA
B17            00002           2019-10-01                NA
```

I would like to use data.frame_2 to fill in the spaces in `partner_code` in data.frame_1. (+ all other variables from main data.frame_1):

```
date             clinic_code   partner_code  
2019-10-01       A05           00033
2019-11-01       A05           00033
                .....
2020-09-01       A05           00033 
2020-10-01       A05           00033
2019-10-01       A12           00001 
2019-11-01       A12           00001         
2019-12-01       A12           00001        
2020-01-01       A12           00044
                              .......
2020-10-01       A12           00044
2019-10-01       B17           00002
2019-11-01       B17           00002
2019-12-01       B17           00002
2020-01-01       B17           00002
2020-02-01       B17           00002
                              .......
2020-03-01       B17           00045
2020-04-01       B17           00045 
2020-05-01       B17           00049 
                              .......
2020-10-01       B17           00049
```

My criteria is: fill in data.frame_1 on `partner_code` any extra info on `partner_code` from data.frame 2. My 3 possible scenarios:

1. A05 - data.frame_1 does not have any info on `partner_code` for A05 and I use the info from data.frame_2 from `partnership_start_date` (2019-10-01) up to `partnership_end_date` (If NA, means it did not end)
2. A12 - data.frame_1 has SOME info about `partner_code` from a particular date (2020-01-01) but no info before, so I use the info from data.frame_2 from `partnership_start_date` (2019-10-01) up to `partnership_end_date` (2019-12-31).
3. B17 - data.frame_1 has SOME info about `partner_code` from a particular date (2020-03-01) but no info before, so I use the info from data.frame_2 from `partnership_start_date` (2019-10-01) up to `partnership_end_date` (NA=did not end; in this case because there is a `partner_code` from 2020-03-01 in data.frame_1, I do not want to overwrite it and leave whatever is in data.frame_1.

Comment: What are your filling criteria? I can't deduce them from your examples. For instance, why are there so many rows for clinical_code A05 in your expected output, but either data.frame_1 or data.frame_2 shows one row only?

Comment: Many thanks ekoam and sorry if not clear - I've just updated my question with criteria. Re your specific question: each clinic_code goes from 2019-10-01 to 2020-10-01 in my data.frame_1 - please see updated data.frame_1

Comment: Hi, I have some ideas but need further clarification. Row 2 and 3 in data.frame_2 show identical values for both clinic_code and partner_code. Why do you choose row 3 but not  2 to fill in A12 in data.frame_1?

Comment: Sorry for not explained that. It is because data.frame_2 joins 2 data.frames (one from February and one from March) and sometimes we see this scenario where in February (row 2) partnership was still ongoing (NA), but then in March (row 3) it ended. Maybe I will need to remove those rows with NA (like row2) when there is another row for the same clinic_code, partner_code & partnership_start_date and a date set for partnership_end_date. Not sure if you could think of other way to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

prep <- 
  . %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("date"), as.Date))

prep(data.frame_2) %>% 
  group_by(clinic_code, partner_code) %>% 
  slice(which.max(order(partnership_end_date, na.last = FALSE))) %>% 
  mutate(partnership_end_date = if_else(is.na(partnership_end_date), as.Date("2020-10-01"), partnership_end_date)) %>% 
  expand(date = seq.Date(partnership_start_date, partnership_end_date, by = "month"), clinic_code, partner_code) %>% 
  left_join(prep(data.frame_1), ., by = c("date", "clinic_code"), suffix = c("", ".2")) %>% 
  mutate(partner_code = coalesce(partner_code, partner_code.2)) %>% 
  select(-partner_code.2)
```

#### Output

At a glance

```
# A tibble: 39 x 3
   date       clinic_code partner_code
   <date>     <chr>       <chr>       
 1 2019-10-01 A05         00033       
 2 2019-11-01 A05         00033       
 3 2019-12-01 A05         00033       
 4 2020-01-01 A05         00033       
 5 2020-02-01 A05         00033       
 6 2020-03-01 A05         00033       
 7 2020-04-01 A05         00033       
 8 2020-05-01 A05         00033       
 9 2020-06-01 A05         00033       
10 2020-07-01 A05         00033       
# ... with 29 more rows
```

The whole picture

```
         date clinic_code partner_code
1  2019-10-01         A05        00033
2  2019-11-01         A05        00033
3  2019-12-01         A05        00033
4  2020-01-01         A05        00033
5  2020-02-01         A05        00033
6  2020-03-01         A05        00033
7  2020-04-01         A05        00033
8  2020-05-01         A05        00033
9  2020-06-01         A05        00033
10 2020-07-01         A05        00033
11 2020-08-01         A05        00033
12 2020-09-01         A05        00033
13 2020-10-01         A05        00033
14 2019-10-01         A12        00001
15 2019-11-01         A12        00001
16 2019-12-01         A12        00001
17 2020-01-01         A12        00044
18 2020-02-01         A12        00044
19 2020-03-01         A12        00044
20 2020-04-01         A12        00044
21 2020-05-01         A12        00044
22 2020-06-01         A12        00044
23 2020-07-01         A12        00044
24 2020-08-01         A12        00044
25 2020-09-01         A12        00044
26 2020-10-01         A12        00044
27 2019-10-01         B17        00002
28 2019-11-01         B17        00002
29 2019-12-01         B17        00002
30 2020-01-01         B17        00002
31 2020-02-01         B17        00002
32 2020-03-01         B17        00045
33 2020-04-01         B17        00045
34 2020-05-01         B17        00049
35 2020-06-01         B17        00002
36 2020-07-01         B17        00002
37 2020-08-01         B17        00002
38 2020-09-01         B17        00002
39 2020-10-01         B17        00049
```

#### Some key steps

1. `slice(which.max(order(...`

Find the last partnership_end_date for each group of clinic_code and partner_code. Use `na.last = FALSE` to place NAs *before* non-NA values. In this way, we can always get either an NA or the last non-NA partnership_end_date if there is one.

2. `mutate(* = if_else(is.na(*), as.Date("2020-10-01"), *))`

Treat NAs as 2020-10-01 because this is the latest date.

3. `expand(date = seq.Date(partnership_start_date, partnership_end_date, by = "month"), ...)`

Expand each start-end date pair in data.frame_2 to a complete sequence. After the expansion, data.frame_2 and data.frame_1 will have the same format, which looks like this

```
# A tibble: 39 x 3
# Groups:   clinic_code, partner_code [4]
   date       clinic_code partner_code
   <date>     <chr>       <chr>       
 1 2019-10-01 A05         00033       
 2 2019-11-01 A05         00033       
 3 2019-12-01 A05         00033       
 4 2020-01-01 A05         00033       
 5 2020-02-01 A05         00033       
 6 2020-03-01 A05         00033       
 7 2020-04-01 A05         00033       
 8 2020-05-01 A05         00033       
 9 2020-06-01 A05         00033       
10 2020-07-01 A05         00033       
# ... with 29 more rows
```

4. `left_join(prep(data.frame_1), ., by = c("date", "clinic_code"), suffix = c("", ".2"))`

Join data.frame_1 and data.frame_2 (that "." represents data.frame_2) on each matching date and clinic_code. The resultant dataframe will have two "partner_code" columns: one named as "partner_code" from data.frame_1 and another named as "partner_code.2" from data.frame_2. Then, we use `coalesce()` to replace missing values in partner_code with values in partner_code.2.

#### Data

data.frame_1 and data.frame_2 as follows

data.frame_1

```
structure(list(date = c("2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", 
"2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", 
"2020-06-01", "2020-07-01", "2020-08-01", "2020-09-01", "2020-10-01", 
"2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", 
"2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", "2020-07-01", 
"2020-08-01", "2020-09-01", "2020-10-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", 
"2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", 
"2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", "2020-07-01", "2020-08-01", "2020-09-01", 
"2020-10-01"), clinic_code = c("A05", "A05", "A05", "A05", "A05", 
"A05", "A05", "A05", "A05", "A05", "A05", "A05", "A05", "A12", 
"A12", "A12", "A12", "A12", "A12", "A12", "A12", "A12", "A12", 
"A12", "A12", "A12", "B17", "B17", "B17", "B17", "B17", "B17", 
"B17", "B17", "B17", "B17", "B17", "B17", "B17"), partner_code = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "00044", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "00045", 
"00045", "00049", NA, NA, NA, NA, "00049")), row.names = c(NA, 
39L), class = "data.frame")
```

data.frame_2

```
structure(list(clinic_code = c("A05", "A12", "A12", "A12", "B17"
), partner_code = c("00033", "00001", "00001", "00044", "00002"
), partnership_start_date = c("2019-10-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-10-01", 
"2020-01-01", "2019-10-01"), partnership_end_date = c(NA, NA, 
"2019-12-31", NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: thanks very much @ekoam for taking the time to look at this. It seems that the 'across' function is still only available in the development version of dplyr, not on CRAN yet. Is there other way to do this instead of using 'across'? It could not find the 'across' function, so I get an error.

Comment: Pleased update your dplyr package to the latest CRAN version. across should be available.

Comment: Older syntax `mutate_at(vars(ends_with("date")), as.Date)`

Comment: I have just done install.library("tidyverse") & library(tidyverse) and then on top install.library("dplyr") & library(dplyr) which I assume is installing automatically the latest CRAN version? But I keep getting the message that 'across' does not exist. Anyway, with the older syntax works, thanks! I will now check the output.

Comment: this is great ekoam, I have done some checks and everything seems to be working as intended. Thank you! I realised that those rows with NAs for the same clinic_code, partner_code and partnership_start_date were appearing after the row with partnership_end_date on my dataset (as opposed to what I have in my question which is before), and because of your 1st point on 'Some key steps', to avoid any issues, I removed those rows from data.frame_2 before running your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `fuzzyjoin` to join based on the range :

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  mutate(partnership_end_date = replace(partnership_end_date, 
                                is.na(partnership_end_date), Sys.Date())) %>%
  fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_right_join(df1, by = c('clinic_code', 
               'partnership_start_date' = 'date', 'partnership_end_date' = 'date'), 
                match_fun = list(`==`, `<=`, `>=`)) %>%
  mutate(partner_code = coalesce(partner_code.y, partner_code.x))
```

Comment: many thanks Ronak for your proposed solution. I had to also load fuzzyjoin package, but then I got an error saying 'Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)'.

Comment: How big is your data? Number of rows vs columns?

Comment: Not big, I think. data.frame_1 = 88761 obs. of 12 variables &
data.frame_2 = 6824 obs. of 5 variables, thanks!